# Recursive call in mySQL

Tags: mysql, recursive-query

I have some data which has three columns

```
+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
+------+------+------+
|  a   |  1   |  p   |
|  a   |  3   |  q   |
|  1   |  b   |  r   |
|  1   |  c   |  s   |
|  3   |  x   |  t   |
|  b   |  l   |  u   |
|  b   |  x   |  v   |
|  c   |  t   |  w   |
|  c   |  z   |  m   |
+------+------+------+
```

Column 1 entries can have more than 1 value.

Now if user searches for 1 in the table, it returns all the values corresponding to 1,

now all entries corresponding to b in column 1 should be repeated and so on.. so if user searches for 1 the output should be

```
+------+------+
| col1 | col2 |
+------+------+
|  1   |  b   |
|  1   |  c   |
|  3   |  x   |
|  b   |  o   |
|  b   |  x   |
|  c   |  t   |
|  c   |  z   |
+------+------+
```

Can somebody help me with the select query.?

Comment: please improve this question concerning what column(s) you mean when you say searches for 1. This question is ambiguous

Comment: @Drew searches for 1 indicates searching the entry in the table in col 1.

Comment: I can do this, but I think your output would look different, and just assume your above result is not what it would be based on my read of it all. And assume the data for your 2nd chunk is not accurate. For instance, why isnt `b,l` in the output for one thing

Comment: @Drew You are right it got in by mistake i.e. b,0 instead it would be b,1 instead.. Can you provide a sample code or something for this...

Comment: I dont even know your schema or your query. Provide it all with sample data and tell what your expected results look like and we can help